# Postman command line arguments (Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, postman

**EDIT**

I've openned an issue on their GitHub and it was marked as a feature request:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3165

So yeah, there are no command line arguments right now.

---

I'm using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test an ASP.NET WebAPI.

I've added Postman executable as a "browser" in Visual Studio, like this:

[image]

The problem is, it simply runs the client without browsing to the debug URL.

Is there a command line for postman.exe in which you can define the starting url?

Also, I was reading about "Newman" but it doesn't seem to be what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the wrong of directly typing the URL in Postman?

Comment: practicality, of course.